# Correct Usage of pygame.key.set_repeat()

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame, and I'm trying to set the pygame.key.set_repeat() so that when a key is held down, nothing will happen. I want to have to click the key again before any action takes place. In the pygame.key docs, it says:

```
pygame.key.set_repeat()

set_repeat() -> None
set_repeat(delay) -> None
set_repeat(delay, interval) -> None
```

I thought that meant that if I did `pygame.key.set_repeat()` with no parameters, that it would automatically turn off any repeating. I also tried `pygame.time.delay()`, but it was really finicky and would only work sometimes. Anyone know how to use this function correctly?

Comment: Do yuo use the keyboard events or `pygame.key.get_pressed()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pygame.key.set_repeat()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat) to control how held keys are repeated:

> When the keyboard repeat is enabled, keys that are held down will generate multiple `pygame.KEYDOWN` events. [...]
>
> [...] To disable key repeat call this function with no arguments or with delay set to 0.

Therefore `pygame.key.set_repeat()` just prevents the `pygame.KEYDOWN` to occur repeatedly.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Hence `pygame.key.set_repeat()` does **not** affect `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I was using `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to see if keys were getting pressed instead of `pygame.KEYDOWN`.